# How to access Java information in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, database

I'm still learning programming, and for one of my assignments I need to create a web page for displaying the positions of some vehicles in a map. While I know Java and a little bit of Javascript, and I'm going to use a data base that I already know (ArangoDB), I'm not sure how to communicate the Java side with Javascript. On Java I created the repository for the data on the DB, with functions like insertEntity, getEntity(key), etc, and I have the structure for those entities in Java too (Vehicle class, BaseEntity class, Position class).

I need to access that information inside of Java with Javascript for displaying it on the map I got (Leaflet, works using JS).

I never created a complete application using different languages, so I'm lost on how to proceed here. While ArangoDB has a JS driver, I wanted to use the Java driver because I like more how you can strcuture objects in that language.

Currently I created a Maven project (first time using it) and I'm using ManagedBean from JSF for accessing some specific data and displaying it on a xhtml page. But I'm just messing around with this, seeing what works out of the box and what doesn't.

Even a reference to a resource for doing this (I'm guessing this falls under web developement) would be appreciated, as until this point the only things we've done are console programs.

Edit 1:
For clarification, the information in the database is being retrived by Java (backend) and I need that information in Javascript for displaying it on the map (frontend).

Comment: Just to understand this correctly, you need your front-end code (JavaScript) to send and receive data from your backend (Java) application?

Comment: My guess is what you want to google here is 'REST api.' It's the most common approach to developing backend services that communicate with web clients, using HTTP as the protocol and generally using JSON as the data serialization format.

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas, yes, that would be it!